# file object has no attribute description

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

[1] Ошибка при отправке сообщения вместе с файлом, сталкивался с такой же проблемой при отправке gif, насколько помню, раньше такого не было. Как это исправить?
Ошибка:

```
Ignoring exception in slash command 'bs_unlock_icons':
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/disnake/ext/commands/slash_core.py", line 681, in invoke
    await call_param_func(self.callback, inter, self.cog, **kwargs)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/disnake/ext/commands/params.py", line 827, in call_param_func
    return await maybe_coroutine(safe_call, function, **kwargs)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/disnake/utils.py", line 580, in maybe_coroutine
    return await value
  File "<string>", line 92, in bs_unlock_icons  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/disnake/interactions/base.py", line 906, in send_message
    await adapter.create_interaction_response(  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/disnake/webhook/async_.py", line 422, in create_interaction_response
    set_attachments(data, files)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/disnake/http.py", line 149, in set_attachments
    "description": file.description,
AttributeError: 'File' object has no attribute 'description'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/disnake/ext/commands/interaction_bot_base.py", line 1262, in process_application_commands
    await app_command.invoke(interaction)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/disnake/ext/commands/slash_core.py", line 690, in invoke
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
disnake.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'File' object has no attribute 'description'
```

Код

```
@client.slash_command(description="Открыть все иконки профиля")
async def bs_hack_icons(inter):
    file = list(csv.reader(open("system/files/player_thumbnails.csv", "r")))
    a = file[0].index("IsReward")
        
    for i in file:
        if i[a] == "true":
            i[a] = ""
            b = file[0].index("IsAvailableForOffers")
            for i in file:
                if i[b] == "true":
                    i[b] = ""
            with open("csv/player_thumbnails.csv","w") as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                for i in file:
                    writer.writerow(i)
    await inter.response.send_message("Иконки профиля открыты. ", file=discord.File('system/files/player_thumbnails.csv', filename='player_thumbnails.csv'))
```

заметил, что python жалуется на последнюю строку, т.е. отправку сообщения.

Comment: полный текст ошибки, пожалуйста

Comment: изменил сообщение.